# SQL Server Count on a grouped by

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I got 3 tables. I want to group by the item.name and count the times it can be found in idetail. This query only counts all rows not the grouped by rows.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
SELECT i.name, COUNT(i.name)
FROM item AS i
INNER JOIN item_category AS ic ON i.i_category_id = ic.ic_id
INNER JOIN idetail AS id ON ic.ic_id = id.id_category_id
WHERE ic.ic_id = 1002
GROUP BY i.name
```

Comment: Something must be wrong or I've missed something. `This query only counts all rows not the grouped by rows.` Sir, from what I can see, this script calculates `COUNT(*)` with grouping, and does it correctly, i.e. the results must be the figures for every `item.name`, not the count of all rows. What output do you actually get?

Comment: I'm also a little confused as to what you actually want - can you elaborate with an example?  Perhaps you intend something like `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) . . .` or `SELECT i.name, COUNT(id.id_id) FROM . . . LEFT JOIN idetail id . . . GROUP BY i.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
select x.name
     , count(*) as cntNames
     , sum(x.cntDetails) as cntDetails
  from (
        SELECT i.name, COUNT(*) as cntDetails
          FROM item AS i
         INNER JOIN item_category AS ic ON i.i_category_id = ic.ic_id
         INNER JOIN idetail AS id ON ic.ic_id = id.id_category_id
         WHERE ic.ic_id = 1002
          -- NOTICE THE 2nd Value in the group by!
         GROUP BY i.name,id.id_category_id
       ) x
  group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select  Count(*)
From    (
            Select i.name, Count(i.name)
            From item As I
                Join item_category As ic
                    On ic.ic_id = i.category_id
                Join idetail as ID
                    On ID.id_category_id = ic.ic_id
            Where ic.ic_id = 1002
            Group By i.name
            ) As Z
```

If you want all three columns and you are using SQL Server 2005+

```
With Items As
    (
    Select I.name, Count(i.name) As ItemCount
    From item As I
        Join item_category As ic
            On ic.ic_id = i.category_id
        Join idetail as ID
            On ID.id_category_id = ic.ic_id
    Where ic.ic_id = 1002
    Group By i.name
    )
Select Name, ItemCount
    ,   (
        Select Count(*)
        From Items
        ) As OverallCount
From Items
```

Another simpler version if you are using SQL Server 2005+.

```
Select i.name
    , Count(i.name) As CountByName
    , Count(*) Over() As TotalCount
From item As I
    Join item_category As ic
        On ic.ic_id = i.category_id
    Join idetail as ID
        On ID.id_category_id = ic.ic_id
Where ic.ic_id = 1002
Group By i.name
```