# Select Rows that appear more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
   TableOne

      PersonId        PersonScore
         1                10
         1                20
         2                99
         2                40
         3                45
```

I need to fetch only those rows where PersonId appears More than Once e.g. Following is the resultset i want to achieve

```
     PersonId        PersonScore
         1                10
         1                20
         2                99
         2                40
```

i am using cte

```
  ;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.PersonId ORDER BY i.PersonId) AS [Num]
   FROM    TableOne i
   )
   SELECT  *
   FROM    cte
   WHERE   cte.Num > 1
```

The problem is it removes the extra rows. It romoves the first instance of any PersonId. Can anyone suggest a solution please

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Count on a grouped by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700155/sql-server-count-on-a-grouped-by)

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: he doesnt want to count anything but get  complete rows which contain a PersonId that is not unique. So a `GROUP BY` is the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `count(*)` as a window function, rather than `row_number()`:

```
select t.PersonId, t.PersonScore
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by PersonId) as cnt
      from TableOne t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableOne t1
JOIN (SELECT PersonId
      FROM TableOne
      GROUP BY PersonId
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
on t1.PersonId = t2.PersonId
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use  a simple correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT PersonId, PersonScore
FROM dbo.TableOne t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM dbo.TableOne t2 
       WHERE t1.PersonId = t2.PersonID) > 1
```