# Rewriting MySQL query without using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table information:
Table name is Teaches,

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | varchar(5)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| course_id | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sec_id    | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| semester  | varchar(6)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| year      | decimal(4,0) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The requirement is to find which course appeared more than once in 2009(ID is the id of teachers)

Here is my query using `GROUP BY`:

```
select course_id 
from teaches 
where year= 2009 
group by course_id 
having count(id) >= 2;
```

How could I write this without using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Why you need to without using group by--

Comment: Homework no doubt ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.course_id
FROM
    teaches T
WHERE
    T.course_id NOT IN (
        SELECT 
          T1.course_id
        FROM teaches AS T1 INNER JOIN teaches AS T2 ON T1.course_id = T2.course_id
        AND T1.`year` = T2.`year`
        AND T1.id <> T2.id
        WHERE   T1.`year` = 2009
    );
```

---

**Test Schema And Data**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teaches`;
CREATE TABLE `teaches` (
  `ID` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_id` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_id` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `semester` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` decimal(4,0) DEFAULT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `teaches` VALUES ('66', '100', 'B', '11', '2009');
INSERT INTO `teaches` VALUES ('71', '100', 'A', '11', '2009');
INSERT INTO `teaches` VALUES ('64', '102', 'C', '12', '2010');
INSERT INTO `teaches` VALUES ('77', '102', 'B', '22', '2009');
```

**Expected Output:**

```
course_id
   102
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ecee8/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

For your homework, below sql can be done.

 This is followed your logic, id exist more than once is means course appeared more than once.

```
select DISTINCT T1.course_id 
from teaches T1
where T1.course_id not in (
select a.course_id 
from teaches as a inner join teaches as b
on a.course_id = b.course_id and a.year = b.year and a.id <> b.id
where a.year= 2009 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
    select t.course_id
from (select t.*, count(*) as cnt from teaches t where year= 2009 ) t
where cnt > 1
```

Try to use stack overflow to search before posting a question,

[Select Rows that appear more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509939/select-rows-that-appear-more-than-once)

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work:

```
select distinct course_id
from teaches o
where (select count(1) from teaches i where i.course_id = o.course_id and i.[year] = 2009) > 1
```